# iPhone NSXMLParser parsing string and storing in a NSNumber variable and different data types

Tags: ios, iphone, types, floating-point, nsxmlparser

I am trying to parse a XML File using NSXMLParser, I also have a Container class, in which I have a few instance variables.  One of the elements that I am trying to parse in the XML is:

`<book sn="32.859669048339128" pn="-116.917800670489670">`

I am trying to save the value of sn and pn in an instance variable of object Container: `NSNumber *sn, NSNumber *pn`.

I want it so that when my parser get the attributeValues it can save it as a Double (or float) in those NSNumber pointers.

Right now, all it does it just saves a string to the NSNumber.

The Parser Code looks like this:

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"book"]){

    container = [[Container alloc] init];

    container.sn=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"sn"];
    container.pn=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"pn"];
}
```

I want it so that the type of container.sn is initialized to a float or double.  Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

So you want to take a float value in a string and create an NSNumber?

```
container.sn = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[string floatValue]];
```